# Como generar un Select en HTML con datos de mysql utilizando node?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, select, express.js

no tengo mucha experiencia como desarrollador y me encuentro frente a un desafio para mi. En mi proyecto estoy utilizando Node, Express, Handlebars, bootstrap entre otros.
Necesito hacer un  con datos de una tabla de MySQL que al seleccionar el dato me complete otros campos del mismo formulario (con datos de la tabla antes mencionada)

Aclaro un poco las cosas, llenar un select con una tabla de MySQL en donde se vea solo un campo de la tabla ("nombre") pero necesito que al seleccionar un nombre se autocompleten otros campos del formulario como "domicilio" y "telefono" que se encuentran en el registro del nombre seleccionado.

Espero que me puedan dar una mano, y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar desde la Documentacion de Handlebars. si a alguien le pasa algo parecido con gusto puedo responderles.
Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Por favor, leé [answer], [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Tu pregunta está basada en opiniones, ¡y tu respuesta no es respuesta! Pensalo: si alguien en unos años con un problema similar llega a tu pregunta, ¿cómo serás capaz de responder? Tené siempre presente que este sitio _no es un foro ni una red social_: tanto las preguntas como las respuestas deben estar presentes en un solo lugar, solo con información relevante. La respuesta debe ser _completa_, y la pregunta no debe parecer [un ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433).